# Where is it best to handle the business logic in my Polymer app?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

So I've got a pure Polymer app. Currently, in some elements I have methods that call to my Firebase database, and handle related processing and whatnot, which I then `<template repeat=...>` into my element. This doesn't seem right, as it's encouraged that Polymer elements are reusable. I also do things like dependency injection e.g. `<my-element app="{{app}}">` so I have access to global settings and such.

What I end up with is a structure like:

```
index.dart -> <my-app-as-an-element app=... -> <child-elements app=...
```

Is there a better way to architect things? Like, should the business logic happen in lib/src/some_controller.dart which is imported into index.dart and has the business logic methods? How would I pass that through to the child elements that need access to those methods? Basically, some best practices and approaches would be helpful.

Code: http://github.com/davenotik/dart-stack/tree/dev

Comment: another potential way to look at it is the child polymer elements generate messages which bubble up and are caught by parent elements, and the data processed. So the child elements don't need access to the overall app, just to generate and throw messages that something else later catches. http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/communication.html

Comment: Best place to handle a business logic is a server side code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Model classes which are structured in a way that reflects the GUI structure and I bind them to the Polymer elements like shown below.
Similar with the controllers but this would get out of proportion for an SO answer.

I didn't test this code - this is just to demonstrate the idea.

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

class AppModel {
  var loginModel = new LoginModel();
  var moviesModel = new MoviesModel();
  var actorsModel = new ActorsModel();
}

class LoginModel extends Observable {
  @observable bool isAuthenticated;
  @observable String userName;
  @observable String email;
}

class MoviesModel {
  final List<MovieModel> movies = toObservable(<MovieModel>[]);
}

class MovieModel extends Observable {
  @observable String id;
  @observable String name;
  @observable int rating;
  final List<ActorModel> actors = toObservable(<ActorModel>[]);
}

class ActorsModel {
  final List<ActorModel> actors = toObservable(<ActorModel>[]);
}

class ActorModel extends Observable {
  @observable String id;
  @observable String firstName;
  @observable String middleName;
  @observable String lastName;
  @observable DateTime birthDate;
  final List<MovieModel> movies = toObservable(<MovieModel>[]);
}
```

.

```dart
<polymer-element name="login-dropdown">
  <template>
    <template if="model.isAuthenticated">
      <label for="userName"><input id="userName" value="{{model.userName}}" disabled></label>
      <label for="email"><input id="email" value="{{model.email}}" disabled></label>
      <button on-click="{{handleSignOut}}">Sign out</button>
    </template>
    <template if="!model.isAuthenticated">
      <label for="userName"><input id="userName" value="{{model.userName}}"></label>
      <button on-click="{{handleSignIn}}">Sign out</button>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart">
    import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
    import 'model.dart';
    @CustomTag('login-dropdown')
    class LoginDropdown extends PolymerElement {
      LoginDropdown.created() : super.created();

      @PublishedProperty(reflect: true) MoviesModel model;
    }
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="app-element">
  <template>
    <header-toolbar>
      <login-dropdown-button>
        <login-dropdown model="{{model.loginModel}}"></login-dropdown>
      </login-dropdown-button>
    </header-toolbar>
    <tab-control>

      <tab-panel label="Movies">
        <movies-panel model="{{model.moviesModel}}"></movies-panel>
      </tab-panel>

      <tab-panel label="Actors">
        <actors-panel model="{{model.actorsModel}}"></actors-panel>
      </tab-panel>

    </tab-control>

  </template>
  <script type="application/dart">
    import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
    import 'model.dart';

    @CustomTag('app-element')
    class AppElement extends PolymerElement {
      AppElement.created() : super.created();

      AppModel model = new AppModel();
    }
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="movies-panel">
  <template>
    <template repeat="{{movie in model.movies}}">
      <movie-panel model="{{movie}}"></movie-panel>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart">
    import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
    import 'model.dart';

    @CustomTag('movies-panel')
    class MoviesPanel extends PolymerElement {
      MoviesPanel.created() : super.created();

      @PublishedProperty(reflect: true) MoviesModel model;
    }
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="movie-panel">
  <template>
    <div data-id="{{model.id}}">
      <div><span>Name:</span><span>{{model.name}}</span></div>
      <div><span>Rating:</span><span>{{model.rating}}</span></div>
    </div>

    <template repeat="{{actor in model.actors}}">
      <actor-panel model="{{actor}}"></actor-panel>
    </template>

  </template>
  <script type="application/dart">
    import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
    import 'model.dart';

    @CustomTag('movies-panel')
    class MoviesPanel extends PolymerElement {
      MoviesPanel.created() : super.created();

      @PublishedProperty(reflect: true) MoviesModel model;
    }
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="actors-panel">
  <template>
    <template repeat="{{actor in model.actors}}">
      <actor-panel model="{{actor}}"></actor-panel>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart">
    import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
    import 'model.dart';

    @CustomTag('actors-panel')
    class ActorsPanel extends PolymerElement {
      ActorsPanel.created() : super.created();

      @PublishedProperty(reflect: true) ActorsModel model;
    }
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="actor-panel">
  <template>
    <div data-id="{{model.id}}">
      <div><span>First name:</span><span>{{model.firstName}}</span></div>
      <div><span>Middle name:</span><span>{{model.middleName}}</span></div>
      <div><span>Last name:</span><span>{{model.lastName}}</span></div>
      <div><span>Date of birth:</span><span>{{model.birthDate}}</span></div>
    </div>

    <template repeat="{{movie in model.movies}}">
      <movie-panel model="{{movie}}"></movie-panel>
    </template>

  </template>
  <script type="application/dart">
    import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
    import 'model.dart';

    @CustomTag('actor-panel')
    class ActorPanel extends PolymerElement {
      ActorPanel.created() : super.created();

      @PublishedProperty(reflect: true) ActorModel model;
    }
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

See also [Use a class as attribute for a dart polymer element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593981) for more interesting options.

Comment: I guess those are called View Models.

Comment: If you have other models on the client you can of course name them ViewModels ;-) What do you mean with dir structure, where to put the files?

Comment: Yea, but I guess it's like: lib/src/client/view_model/app.dart, movies.dart, movie.dart... I like how you have AppModel, which eliminates the need for DI w/ app=?

Comment: I wouldn't use a `client` subdirectory. Server and client shouldn't be in the same package anyway. If client and server share code I would create a package my_app_shared and move the shared code into this package.